# Flask Audio File to Wave Object Python

Tags: python, rest, post, flask, wav

I want to convert an audio file received from flask api (of type class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage') to a Wave (https://pypi.org/project/Wave/) object. Usually, you do this by supplying a path on your comp:

```
import wave
wav = wave.open("test.wav", "r")
```

But this doesn't work as I do not want to save the audio file to my computer. This is how I get the audio file in my flask script:

```
audio = request.files["audio"]
```

Please let me know what I can do! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following modification of your code:

```
audio = request.files['audio_file']
```

The `request.files` is a dictionary. The dictionary key that will allow you to retrieve the audio file is 'audio_file' instead of 'audio'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use save() function

```
  audio = request.files["audio"]
    path='./videos/sample.wav';
    audio.save(path)
```

check for further details
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save